# Angular slide animation of router-outlet content extension

Tags: angular, animation

I have successfully implemented a `SlideUpDown`-Animation which allows to slide up and down dynamically added content inside the router outlet. I am using `max-height` in order to achieve this.

If I click a `routerLink`, the content slides down and it is visible, if I click the same link again, it slides up. But assume I click `link A`, which renders the content of `Component A` inside `router-outlet`, and then I click `link B`, no further animation is triggered, but the height of the wrapping container around the `router-outlet` is modified instantly. This is obvious because I use the `max-height` attribute.

I altered the animation and added a third state, `'add_in'`, which is triggered when the wrapper is already slided down. I also tried to get the height of the wrapper, but again and obviously, the height is not calculated right yet, because this `div` has not yet got his final height (which would be awesome because I could place the animation inside the component file and use a binding to a property and set this in the `max-height` attribute).

How can I achieve this behaviour? Let's say `Component A` is rendered in `router-outlet` with a height of 200px, and then I click `Link B` which triggers the rendering of `Component B` with a height of 500px, I want to animate the modification of 200px to 500px.

This is my current code:

**slide.animation.ts**

```
export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
        state('in', style({
            'max-height': '800px', visibility: 'visible'
        })),
        state('out', style({
            'max-height': '0px', visibility: 'hidden'
        })),
        state('add_in', style({
            'max-height': '800px', visibility: 'visible'
        })),
        transition('* => out', [group([
            animate('600ms ease-out', style({
                'max-height': '0px'
            })),
            animate('600ms ease-out', style({
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }))
        ]
        )]),
        transition('out => in', [group([
            animate('1ms ease-out', style({
                visibility: 'visible'
            })),
            animate('600ms ease-out', style({
                'max-height': '800px'
            }))
          ])
        ]),
        transition('in => add_in', [group([
            animate('1ms ease-out', style({
                visibility: 'visible'
            })),
            animate('600ms ease-out', style({
                'max-height': '800px'
            }))
          ])
        ])
      ])
  ];
```

**bubble-nav.component.html**

```
<a class="bubble-nav-item" [routerLink]="['/bubbles/bubble01']" (click)="onClickMenuItem('bubble01')">
      <img src="assets/bubble-nav-icons/awb3.png" />
      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <p>{{ titleBubbleCommunication }}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
<a class="bubble-nav-item" [routerLink]="['/bubbles/bubble02']" (click)="onClickMenuItem('bubble02')">
      <img src="assets/bubble-nav-icons/awb4.png" />
      <div class="title-wrapper">
        <p>{{ titleBubbleCommunication }}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
// (...)
```

**bubble-nav.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bubble-nav',
  // ...
})
export class BubbleNavComponent {
  // ...
  @Output() menuClicked = new EventEmitter();
  // ...
  onClickMenuItem(event: any) {
    this.menuClicked.emit(event);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-bubble-nav (menuClicked)="onMenuItemClicked($event)></app-bubble-nav>

<div class="expandable-content" [@slideInOut]="animationState">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  // ...
  animationState = 'in';
  currentBubble = '';

  // ...

  onMenuItemClicked(elementName) {

    if (this.currentBubble === elementName) {
        this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
    } else {
      switch (this.animationState) {
        case 'in':
          this.animationState = 'add_in';
          break;
        case 'out':
          this.animationState = 'in';
          break;
      }
    }

    this.currentBubble = elementName;
  }
}
```

How can I change the transition `'in => add_in'` to achieve this behaviour?